# JMS over SSL on jBoss AS 7

Tags: ssl, jboss, jms, netty, jboss-eap-6

I'm trying to make my jms client work over ssl, but after configuring of jboss i have an exception

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. log4j:WARN See
>   http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
>   Mar 21, 2013 4:20:26 PM cz.bleble.DummyJMS
>   main INFO: Attempting to acquire connection factory
>   "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" Mar 21, 2013 4:20:27 PM
>   cz.bleble.DummyJMS main INFO: Found
>   connection factory "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" in JNDI Mar 21, 2013
>   4:20:27 PM cz.bleble.DummyJMS main INFO:
>   Attempting to acquire destination "jms/queue/Online" Mar 21, 2013
>   4:20:27 PM cz.bleble.DummyJMS main INFO:
>   Found destination "jms/queue/Online" in JNDI Mar 21, 2013 4:20:27 PM
>   cz.bleble.DummyJMS main SEVERE: Failed to
>   create session factory 15:20:27,908 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming]
>   (Remoting "esekilx5066" task-3) JBAS011806: Channel end notification
>   received, closing channel Channel ID 12d4350a (inbound) of Remoting
>   connection 5c0673b4 to /192.168.4.25:63316 Exception in thread
>   "main" javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
>           at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:605)
>           at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:119)
>           at cz.bleble.DummyJMS.main(DummyJMS.java:94)
>   Caused by: HornetQException[errorCode=2 message=Cannot connect to
>   server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
>           at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:775)
>           at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:601)
>           ... 2 more

this is my client:

```
package cz.bleble;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

public final class DummyJMS {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(DummyJMS.class.getName());

    private static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "Hello, World!";
    private static final String DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY = "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
    private static final String DEFAULT_DESTINATION = "jms/queue/Online";
    private static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE_COUNT = "1";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "user";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "pass";
    private static final String INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory";
    private static final String PROVIDER_URL = "remote://192.168.4.25:4447";

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
        Connection connection = null;
        Session session = null;
        MessageProducer producer = null;
        MessageConsumer consumer = null;
        Destination destination = null;
        TextMessage message = null;
        Context context = null;

        try {
            // Set up the context for the JNDI lookup
            final Properties env = new Properties();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
            env.put("remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", "true");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL));
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, System.getProperty("username", DEFAULT_USERNAME));
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, System.getProperty("password", DEFAULT_PASSWORD));
            env.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
            context = new InitialContext(env);

            // Perform the JNDI lookups
            String connectionFactoryString = System.getProperty("connection.factory", DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY);
            LOG.info("Attempting to acquire connection factory \"" + connectionFactoryString + "\"");
            connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup(connectionFactoryString);
            LOG.info("Found connection factory \"" + connectionFactoryString + "\" in JNDI");

            String destinationString = System.getProperty("destination", DEFAULT_DESTINATION);
            LOG.info("Attempting to acquire destination \"" + destinationString + "\"");
            destination = (Destination) context.lookup(destinationString);
            LOG.info("Found destination \"" + destinationString + "\" in JNDI");

            // Create the JMS connection, session, producer, and consumer
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(System.getProperty("username", DEFAULT_USERNAME), System.getProperty("password", DEFAULT_PASSWORD));
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
            connection.start();

            int count = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("message.count", DEFAULT_MESSAGE_COUNT));
            String content = System.getProperty("message.content", DEFAULT_MESSAGE);

            LOG.info("Sending " + count + " messages with content: " + content);

            // Send the specified number of messages
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                message = session.createTextMessage(content);
                producer.send(message);
            }

            // Then receive the same number of messages that were sent
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                message = (TextMessage) consumer.receive(5000);
                LOG.info("Received message with content " + message.getText());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.severe(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        } finally {
            // closing the connection takes care of the session, producer, and consumer
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
            if (context != null) {
              context.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this are peaces of my standalone.xml from jboss

```
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.3">

    <extensions>
        ...
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.messaging"/>
        ...
    </extensions>

    ...

    <profile>
        ...
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.2">
            <hornetq-server>
                <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
                <security-enabled>true</security-enabled>
                <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>
                <journal-file-size>102400</journal-file-size>
                <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

                <connectors>
                    <netty-connector name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                        <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    </netty-connector>
                    <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                    <netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging">
                      <param key="ssl-enabled" value="true"/>
                      <param key="key-store-path" value="/keystore"/>
                      <param key="key-store-password" value="changeme"/>
                    </netty-connector>    
                </connectors>

                <acceptors>
                    <netty-acceptor name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                        <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                        <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                    </netty-acceptor>
                    <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                    <netty-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging">
                      <param key="ssl-enabled" value="true"/>
                      <param key="key-store-path" value="/keystore"/>
                      <param key="key-store-password" value="changeme"/>
                      <param key="trust-store-path" value="/truststore"/>
                        <param key="trust-store-password" value="changeme"/>
                      </netty-acceptor>
                </acceptors>

                <security-settings>
                    <security-setting match="#">
                        <permission type="send" roles="user"/>
                        <permission type="consume" roles="user"/>
                        <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="user"/>
                        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="user"/>
                        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="user"/>
                        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="user"/>
                    </security-setting>
                </security-settings>

                <address-settings>
                    <address-setting match="#">
                        <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                        <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                        <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
                        <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
                        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                    </address-setting>
                </address-settings>

                <jms-connection-factories>
                    <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
                        <connectors>
                            <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                        </connectors>
                        <entries>
                            <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
                            <entry name="java:/XAConnectionFactory"/>
                        </entries>
                    </connection-factory>
                    <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
                        <connectors>
                            <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
                        </connectors>
                        <entries>
                            <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>         
                        </entries>
                    </connection-factory>  
                    <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                        <transaction mode="xa"/>
                        <connectors>
                            <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                        </connectors>
                        <entries>
                            <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                        </entries>
                    </pooled-connection-factory>
                </jms-connection-factories>

                <jms-destinations>
                    <jms-queue name="Online">
                        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/Online"/>
                    </jms-queue>
                </jms-destinations>
            </hornetq-server>
        </subsystem>
        ...
    </profile>
    ...
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        ...
        <socket-binding name="messaging" port="5445"/>
        <socket-binding name="messaging-group" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.messaging.group.address:231.7.7.7}" multicast-port="${jboss.messaging.group.port:9876}"/>
        <socket-binding name="messaging-throughput" port="5455"/>
        <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
        <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
        ...
    </socket-binding-group>

</server>
```

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?
I cannot find any working example of jms coonfiguration and client for jboss as7 over ssl...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not sure I'm familiar with port 4447.  I believe HornetQ listens on port 5545 for SSL.